# Looping xcopy script

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy, robocopy

Trying to use `xcopy` but when I put it in a batch script as:

```
Xcopy "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\A" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\B" /E
```

and run it...it loops over and over again. But if I paste that line into command line and hit enter it works. Why is this and how do I fix this? Robocopy works fine in a script.

Comment: is this the only code in your script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the name of your batch script "Xcopy.bat" ? If yes change the name....

Comment: I had it called copy. I didn't think that would mess it up. Why would that?

Comment: OH. MY. GOD. 1 hour later I realize I can't have a batch file called xcopy.bat OR robocopy.bat!?!?!?! WTF!? I had the "loop" problem and now I still can't believe it that that was the problem the whole time. My new batch file is called whatthef***.bat!